# Is Mata Saraswati really the Goddess of knowledge?

Tags: saraswati

We generally say that Goddess Saraswati is the Goddess of Knowledge and Wisdom and all the knowledge that can ever be attained by the mankind was originated from herself. So if she is indeed the Goddess of knowledge, did she knew about modern day topics like, 'Calculus' and 'Quantum Mechanics'? If yes then why didn't she told the mankind about such useful tools? If no then how is her title of "Goddess of Wisdom and Knowledge" justified?

Comment: Because Calculus and QM won't help you attain Brahman

Comment: Oh. She did. Did you look at Ramanujan’s theorems?

Comment: @GopalAnantharaman Can you please share some genuine links or proof about your statement I can't really find about it on the internet anywhere.

Comment: @GopalAnantharaman On a side note Ramanujan's theorems were mostly derivations of reimann's zeta function and some mathematical series, which are neither related to QM nor Calculus, no religious offense btw.

Comment: The emigration or end of Nada is itself Mahasarswati, in this Gross body she takes form of Swaras and vayjans, in the subtel body she becomes Nada and at the very end the same Nada becomes pranav and merges back into Mahasarswati. The knowledge essentially as we see outside is the "Expressed" one. What we understand is something entirely distinct, we "interpret" that expression! Why would she tell it, if its already in front of us?